# AJAX POST not working, php doesn't create session

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I want to send id of element to php and create session for this.

This is piece from php file:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT id FROM products";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
?>
    <tr class="table-manufacture-tr">
    <td class="table-manufacture-td-statys">
        <div class="warehouse-window-content-dropdown-plus2 plus">
           <a class="open_item" data-id=<?php echo "\"".$row['p_id']."\"";?> 
            style="text-decoration: none; color: #D3D3D3;">Click</a>
        </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
<?php
}
?>
```

And in this file javascript code:

```
$(document).on('click', '.open_item', function(event){

        var data_item = this.getAttribute("data-id");

        $.ajax({
            url: 'get_id.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data-type: 'json',
            data: { id: data_item },
            contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function(){
                console.log("not working");
            }
        });
    });
```

This is get_id.php:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['item_id'] = json_encode($_POST);
    header("Content-Type: application/json", true);
?>
```

I have tried also without content types and without json. "var data_item" prints id correct, but php doesn't create session and in console also clear(nothing).

Comment: How do you know session is not generated? Have you print session data any where?

Comment: My ajax calls use "dataType" not "data-type".  Is data-type also valid?

Also, is the php returning json data?

Comment: try to replace `data-type` to `dataType`

Answer (score 1):

The reason that you are not getting data in session is, you are not assigning proper value to session. Also it should be `json_decode` not `json_encode`.

replace

```
$_SESSION['item_id'] = json_encode($_POST);
```

with

```
if (!empty($_POST['id'])) {
    $_SESSION['item_id'] = json_decode($_POST['id']); // use json_decode
}
```

Comment: Is the post variable not $_POST["id"]?

Comment: Thanks didn't noticed that

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`$_SESSION['item_id'] = json_encode($_POST['id']);`

instead of

```
$_SESSION['item_id'] = json_encode($_POST);
```

this will work fine.

Comment: Does it need json_encode() at all?  I'm getting the impression this might just be a single string.

Comment: As data-type: 'json' is mentioned, means expecting data in json format, so json_encode will be added.

Comment: It's "dataType", not "data-type".  And it refers to the data type of the expected RESPONSE.  Reference: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are trying to do, but from your JS, it looks like that you are expecting that the PHP script --which you post some data to it-- to return a json with the data you have just posted in it. In that case, try this, change your get_id.php to be like:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['item_id'] = json_encode($_POST);
    header("Content-Type: application/json", true);
    echo $_SESSION['item_id'];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are making some small mistake in your code like you are echoing **`$row['p_id']`** while your query should return `id` instead `p_id` also you are making mistake in `ajax` you are sending `data-type` JavaScript assuming your code is subtracting so try to use this code i code below.

```
// modify your php code
<?php
$sql = "SELECT id FROM products";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>
  <tr class="table-manufacture-tr">
      <td class="table-manufacture-td-statys">
        <div class="warehouse-window-content-dropdown-plus2 plus">
          <a class="open_item" data-id=<?php echo "\"".$row['id']."\"";?> 
          style="text-decoration: none; color: #D3D3D3;">Click</a>
        </div>
      </td>
  </tr>
<?php } ?>

// modify your jQuery
$(document).on('click', '.open_item', function(event){

    var data_item = $(this).data("id");

    $.ajax({
        url: 'get_id.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { id: data_item },
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(){
            console.log("not working");
        }
    });
});


<?php
  session_start();
  header("Content-Type: application/json", true);
  $_SESSION['item_id'] = json_encode($_POST["id"]);
  echo json_encode(['data_id' => $_SESSION['item_id']]);
?>
```

Comment: the `echo ['data_id' => $_SESSION['item_id']];` part will only return a string `Array`, you cannot directly echo an array

Comment: yes my mistake now i adjusted code. please try now.

Comment: you are double `json_encode`-ing, its not wise to send JSON data in a JSON, it would result something like this `{"test":"{\"json\":\"json data\"}"}` where you can just send `{"json":"json data"}`

Comment: the last line is only for testing there is not need for this line you can remove it

Comment: because you only need to set id in session. and for that you can also use only `$_SESSION['item_id'] = $_POST["id"];`

Answer (score 0):

I'd troubleshoot this by making sure the click handler is actually going off.  Put alert("clicked"); as the first thing in the in the click handler to make sure.

For the meantime, remove the contentType in the json call.  Also remove the dataType (data-type) entirely.  On the php side, replace the header() line so (as mentioned) the php is just:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['item_id'] = $_POST["id"];
echo $_SESSION['item_id'];
```

Do not use json_encode/decode right now.  From your code, it is not needed.